# Mnemonics for 汉字: examples and resources

Tags: characters, expressions

Where can one find other mnemonics similar to 
横戌点戍空心戊 and 已半, 巳满, 不出己 ?

Also, what in your opinion are the most common, useful or interesting such mnemonics? What is the term for such mnemonics in 普通话?

Also related, riddles ( 猜字谜) like 一口咬掉牛尾巴 （打一字）. Which are your favourite such riddles?

Edit (2018-08-31) I would be particularly interested in mnemonics used in Chinese schools. Are these called 口诀 or 字诀? Here's another one I just remembered:

```
j, q, x
小淘气
遇到ü
把点去
```

Comment: What I learned at school is 己平已半巳封口

Answer (score 1):

I can only remember other things about the structure of characters.

When someone get name of others, if the surname is Zhang, he may ask 弓长张 or 立早章?

And the most confusing riddle, I think,

一个不出头，两个不出头，三个不出头，不是不出头，就是不出头. (打一字)

When I first know the riddle, I was like, wtf, it doesn't even make sense, what does 不出头 mean? And the most confusing part 不是不出头, 就是不出头.

And when I had got the answer, it became my favorite 汉字 riddle instantly.

Comment: This riddle needs you to crackle every "不出头". Kind of amusing :D

Comment: No idea what the answer is to this riddle! I think I'll wait a while before doing a web search...

Comment: @goPlayerJuggler Don't push yourself hard, I bet no one can work it out by himself, it is really tricky.